# Initialization of base classes in Java when accessing a static field

Tags: java, static, static-initialization

The [Java 21 specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1) states

> A reference to a static field (§8.3.1.1) causes initialization of only the class or interface that actually declares it, even though it might be referred to through the name of a subclass, a subinterface, or a class that implements an interface.

and later

> A class or interface will not be initialized under any other circumstance.

But when I have the following classes

```java
public class Base {
    static {
        System.out.println("Base");
    }
}
public class Derived extends Base  {
    static {
        System.out.println("Derived");
    }
    public static int foo = 2;
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Derived.foo);
    }
}
```

The output of the program is

```
Base
Derived
2
```

It seems to me that the class `Base` is initialized. Why is this the case? Doesn't the specification forbid this?

Comment: Similarly, when I make `Main` a subclass of a class then that class is always initialized as well at the start of the program - which I also don't understand. We are not creating any objects here, so the base classes aren't really needed, are they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are perhaps misunderstanding what "initialization of only the class or interface that actually declares it" means.

Consider this modification to your code:

```
public class Base { ... }
public class Derived extends Base  { ... }

public class Derived2 extends Derived {
    static {
        System.out.println("Derived2");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Derived2.foo);
    }
}
```

If you run this ([Ideone](https://ideone.com/M5ZY9l)), you will find it outputs:

```
Base
Derived
2
```

i.e. it doesn't print `Derived2`.

In order to initialize a class, you have to initialize its superclasses. From [JLS 12.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4):

> When a class is initialized, its superclasses are initialized (if they have not been previously initialized)

but Java doesn't need to initialize `Derived2` in order to print a static symbol from `Derived`.

Comment: Okay, so accessing a static variable causes only an initialization of the class that defines it, but if that class has any super classes, those are always initilized as well, right?

Comment: @abenthy approximately, yes: there is more to the quote from JLS 12.4 than I have posted here, that I omitted because it felt like more detail than was necessary.